# Comparing 2 dates for conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

Trying to apply conditional formatting for week values in google sheets. I have a week column with values 05/Aug/2019, 12/Aug/2019 etc.
I want to fill in uniform colour for all values between 01 and 07 (first week), 08 and 14 (second week) etc. My condition is evaluating to false however, I don't understand why.

```
=IF(VALUE(LEFT(A284, FIND("/",A284) -1)) > 0 & VALUE(LEFT(A284, FIND("/",A284) -1)) <7,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Value A284 = 05/Aug/2019

Also I want to search the whole column and apply the formula for the range but it gives a formula parse error:

```
=IF(VALUE(LEFT(A:A, FIND("/",A:A) -1)) > 0 & VALUE(LEFT(A:A, FIND("/",A:A) -1)) <7,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Part 1 of question:**

It may be a habit from some programming languages to use & as a logical operator (more likely a bitwise AND operator C/Python/Java etc. but OK a logical operator in C#), but in Excel formulas it's a string concatenation operator, so you have to use the AND function instead:

```
=IF(AND(VALUE(LEFT(A284, FIND("/",A284) -1)) > 0, VALUE(LEFT(A284, FIND("/",A284) -1)) <7),TRUE,FALSE)
```

You don't need to use an If statement because the AND produces a logical TRUE/FALSE value on its own:

```
=AND(VALUE(LEFT(A284, FIND("/",A284) -1)) > 0, VALUE(LEFT(A284, FIND("/",A284) -1)) <7)
```

**Part 2 of question**

To appply conditional formatting to the whole range, you simply write the formula appropriately for the top of the range, select the whole range, and add a conditional formatting rule containing the formula. So if the range starts in A284 and continues downwards, the above formula can be applied to the whole range.

[image]

**Note**

Strictly speaking you don't *have* to use the AND function, you can also use multiplication to get a 0/1 value which works equally well in conditional formatting:

```
=(VALUE(LEFT(A284, FIND("/",A284) -1)) > 0)* (VALUE(LEFT(A284, FIND("/",A284) -1)) <7)
```

Answer (score 0):

For google sheets users

```
=AND(VALUE(LEFT($A:$A, 2)) > 0,VALUE(LEFT($A:$A, 2)) < 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

shorter:

```
=(LEFT(A1,2)*1>0)*(LEFT(A1,2)*1<8)
```

[image: 0]